# Apply VLOOKUP to multiple rows

Tags: if-statement, filter, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-vlookup

I am helping with a summer camp and want to be able to look up the amount that a parent has paid. My form gives me the results like this:

[image: Sample data]

I want to be able to do an index lookup of the amount paid if I input either of the persons names in the row.

My code allows me to look up the last name and first name of the first parent but not of the second so I need to add an OR function in it somewhere but I'm not sure where.

```
=INDEX(FILTER(FACTURATION!G:G;FACTURATION!B:B=B3;FACTURATION!C:C=C3);1)
```

[image]

I tried this, but no luck:

```
=INDEX(OR(FILTER(FACTURATION!G:G;FACTURATION!B:B=B3;FACTURATION!C:C=C3);FILTER(FACTURATION!G:G;FACTURATION!E:E=B3;FACTURATION!F:F=C3)))
```

[Link to spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/139U5MrQClXOSdHbEhbndjc5Bl-uxfD_f9ykcNaTE2aU/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out for anyone interested:

=FILTER(**List!G:G;**(List!C:C=B3)*(List!B:B=A3)+(List!F:F=B3)*(List!E:E=A3))

what I want listed

=FILTER(List!G:G;**(List!C:C=B3)*(List!B:B=A3)***+(List!F:F=B3)(List!E:E=A3))

First two criterion (First Name and Last Name)

=FILTER(List!G:G;(List!C:C=B3)*(List!B:B=A3)+**(List!F:F=B3)***(List!E:E=A3))

The second criterieon (First Name and Last Name)

I was missing the operators * = AND // + = OR

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
=IF(OR(List!$C2 = $B2; List!$C2 =$B2);List!$G2;IF(OR(List!$E2=$A2;List!$F2=$B2);List!$G2;List!$G2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this formula work as you want:

`=FILTER(List!G:G;(List!C:C=B3)+(List!B:B=A3))`

Comment: I tried it, but even in the example sheet, it doesn't seem to work, because when I change the name on the cost sheet, the number no longer changes. Both conditions have to be met (first name and last) for either name in the row

Comment: I'm thinking something like this : =FILTER(List!G:G;(List!C:C=B3;List!B:B=A3)+(List!F:F=B3;List!E:E=A3))  but that won't work